# Python web scraping with selenium : finding an element in modal box and downloading it - in loop

Tags: python, selenium, pdf, web-scraping, download

I would like to download files named "sprawozdanie merytoryczne" for 2017 year for each organzation in a Python loop.To download one manually you have to go to website:http://sprawozdaniaopp.mpips.gov.pl/ click button "Znajdź" and click on the name of organization - modal box will appear with a link to "sprawozdanie merytoryczne" for that particular organization. I wanted to do it automatically for all organizations. But I faced some problems. During first run through a loop everything is ok, first file is downloaded. But when it comes to second one it opens a modal window but it doesn't see "sprawozdanie merytoryczne", despite it is present. I think it is something wrong with switching to windows. I would be very grateful for any help. Here is my code:

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
import requests
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import re
import unicodecsv  # import whole module
import requests  # import whole module
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  # import only things that we need
import time
import smtplib
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_path= r"C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35- 
32\Scripts\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get("http://sprawozdaniaopp.mpips.gov.pl/")

rok = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='instanceYear']")
rok.send_keys('2017') 

wojewodztwo = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='Province']")
wojewodztwo.clear()
wojewodztwo.send_keys('MAZOWIECKIE')  
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='btnsearch']/span")
elem.click()
for i in range(1, 1348):
    winhandle = driver.current_window_handle
    p1 = r'#form1 > div > div.grid > table > tbody > tr:nth-child('
    p2 = ') > td:nth-child(3) > a'
    p3 = p1 + str(i) + p2
    elem1 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(p3)
    p1 = r'#form1 > div > div.grid > table > tbody > tr:nth-child('
    p2 = ') > td:nth-child(5)'
    p3 = p1 + str(i) + p2
    miejscowosc = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(p3)
    print(miejscowosc.text) #miejscowosc means city
    miejscowosc1=miejscowosc.text
    p1 = r'#form1 > div > div.grid > table > tbody > tr:nth-child('
    p2 = ') > td:nth-child(4)'
    p3 = p1 + str(i) + p2
    wojewodztwo = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(p3)
    elem1.click()

    WebDriverWait(driver, 
    10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".ui- 
    dialog.ui-widget.ui-widget-content.ui-corner-all")))


    try:
        elem2 = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Sprawozdanie 
        merytoryczne").click()
        organizationName = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("td1")
        orgname = str(organizationName[11].text)

        orgname1 = orgname.replace('"', "")
        print(organizationName[11].text)

        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
        urltemp = driver.current_url
        urltodownload=  requests.get(urltemp)

        path1 = r'C:/Users/adunajsk/Desktop/pdf17maz/'
        path2 = '.pdf'
        path3 = path1 + orgname1 + path2
        print(path3)
        with open(path3, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(urltodownload.content)
        driver.close()

        del organizationName[:] 
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("Plik nie istnieje")

    driver.switch_to.window(winhandle)

    WebDriverWait(driver, 
    8).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "body 
    > div.ui-dialog.ui-widget.ui-widget-content.ui-corner-all > 
    div.ui-dialog-titlebar.ui-widget-header.ui-corner-all.ui-helper- 
    clearfix > a > span")))

    closebutton= driver.find_element_by_css_selector("body > div.ui- 
    dialog.ui-widget.ui-widget-content.ui-corner-all > div.ui-dialog- 
    titlebar.ui-widget-header.ui-corner-all.ui-helper-clearfix > a")
    closebutton.click()
```

Comment: In second run of a loop "driver.find_element_by_link_text("Sprawozdanie 
        merytoryczne").click()" doesn't finish with success 
But in first run it was able to go properly.

Comment: There are more than one "Sprawozdanie merytoryczne" in modal box. Do you need to click on all of them or specific one?

Comment: Where is your `except` block? Which line leading to exception?

Comment: @sers Only the one coming from 2017 year

Comment: @Andersson except NoSuchElementException:
        print("Plik nie istnieje") # meaning file doesn't exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is once you open modal dialog it will stay in DOM even you close it. When you open second your locator find first one and try to click there.
Also you can config driver to directly download pdf without opening it.

Here code:

**Not: I coded and tested it with Java, code may contain syntax errors**

```
    #set chrome options to download pdf instead open it in browser, this will remove need to handle windows and make it much faster
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    downloadPath = r'C:\Users\username\Downloads'
    profile = {"plugins.plugins_list": [{"enabled":False,"name":"Chrome PDF Viewer"}],"download.default_directory" : downloadPath}
    options.add_experimental_option("prefs",profile)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Scripts\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)

    driver.get("http://sprawozdaniaopp.mpips.gov.pl/")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(By.ID, 'Province')).send_keys('MAZOWIECKIE')
    driver.find_element_by_id('instanceYear').send_keys('2017')
    driver.find_element_by_id('btnsearch').click()

    #after search wait table to load data with column with MAZOWIECKIE text
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//table[@class="webgrid"]/tbody//td[normalize-space(.)="MAZOWIECKIE"]')))

    #get all rows and iterate throw, make your code dinamically and not depends row size
    rows = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('table.webgrid tbody tr');
    for row in rows:
        #get KRS column number
        krs = row.find_element_by_css_selector('td:nth-child(2)').text()
        #click to link in Nazwa column
        row.find_element_by_css_selector('td:nth-child(3) a').click()
        #find modal box DIV element with KRS numeber got from click row. as option you can get all modal boxes and get one visible.
        modalBoxLocator = "(//table[@id='tbldetails']//td[contains(.,'" + krs + "')]/ancestor::div[contains(@class,'ui-dialog')][2])[last()]"  
        modalBox = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, modalBoxLocator)))
        #find TD with 2017 text and then click on first "Sprawozdanie merytoryczne" link after 2017
        modalBox.find_element_by_xpath('.//tr[./td[.='2017']]/following-sibling::tr[.//a[.="Sprawozdanie merytoryczne"]][1]//a').click()
        #close modal box
        modalBox.find_element_by_css_selector('a.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').click()

        #if modalBox.find_elements_by_css_selector('a.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').size()>0:
        #   modalBox.find_element_by_css_selector('a.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').click()
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I started to implement it but I faced an error: 
modalBox = driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//table[@id="tbldetails"]//td[contains(.,"' + krs + '")]/ancestor::div[contains(@class,"ui-dialog")][2])[last()]')
TypeError: Can't convert 'WebElement' object to str implicitly

Comment: Try change to `modalBox = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//table[@id='tbldetails']//td[contains(.,'" + krs + "')]/ancestor::div[contains(@class,'ui-dialog')][2])[last()]")`

Comment: After following your direction and aditionally changing krs = row.find_element_by_css_selector('td:nth-child(2)').text() to krs = row.find_element_by_css_selector('td:nth-child(2)').text there appears : 
 Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"(//table[@id='tbldetails']//td[contains(.,'0000009458')]/ancestor::div[contains(@class,'ui-dialog')][2])[last()]"}

Comment: I added wait. Also you can use implicit by adding driver.implicitly_wait(10)

Comment: Another problem happens :( 
modalBox = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(By.XPATH, "(//table[@id='tbldetails']//td[contains(.,'" + krs + "')]/ancestor::div[contains(@class,'ui-dialog')][2])[last()]"))
TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: I'm not using python. I thought you know python enough to fix syntax errors. Check it again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178531/discussion-between-sers-and-ejdi).